# MS Access 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-server-2012

I have created an Access 2016, 32-bit application that is about to be deployed. Every user will access the application through a RDP connection and then onto a MS Server 2012 R2 server (I doubt if it will ever be installed on any other platforms). As far as each user is concerned there will be nothing on the server, except the Access database (using an Access runtime license), and each machine will be pretty much locked down.

All of the libraries used in the Access application are available in either 32-bit or 64-bit formats, plus the back-end databases are usually small (typically between 10MB and 200MB).  That said the compiled Access front-end is about 18MB and can run some rather complex functions/calculations (but nothing on a scientific level).

So finally, my question.  Would there be any real benefit in moving to a 64-bit version (in either the short or long-term)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. 64 bit version doesn't give any useful advantages, but you will have some additional problems with compatibility.

Comment: I think it does give you useful advantages, because you can use more than 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: Right, but I never seen so far Access application, which may require more than 2 Gb of RAM. 2 Gb file size limitation remains even in 64 bit version of Access.

Comment: Thanks guys - in this case, the databases will never be more than 200Mb.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this answer strongly depends on how many RAM your application will need. Because 32 bit is limited to 2 GB or something I think.

So this is not a real question of benefits or performance but of not running into any RAM issues if the amount fo data increases I think.

See also [Choose between the 64-bit or 32-bit version of Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261).

Besides that I see no advantages in choosing 64 bit.

Comment: Again, thank you.  Same as above, the back-end will never be more than 200MB.